# How python 2.7.12 and 2.7.13 are different?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2.7.12 on Spyder, Can  I still learn the Python 2.7.13 documentation be absolutely sure that I will not have any problem?

Comment: There is a thing called CHANGELOG

Comment: StackOverflow is not an advice forum. If you had some particular code that worked in 2.7.12 and not in 2.7.13 then it would be appropriate to post here.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7.13 is a bugfix release, which means there are no major differences you need to be aware of.  The entire 2.7 series documentation is pretty much applicable regardless of which point release you use.

You can read the full details here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/v2.7.13/Misc/NEWS